# Proper way to create a DAO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dao

From an OOP perspective, what is the proper way to create a DAO (Data Access Object) in php?

For example (using Account as a basic example), my AccountDAO will have some of the following functions:

- `GetAllAccounts`
- `GetAccountByID`
- `UpdateAccount`
- `DeleteAccount`
- `InsertAccount`

So once I fetch all of the Accounts in the database, should I return them to the caller as an array of account objects?  Should I just return the mysql result set?

Do you know any good example of a DAO?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track to build a DAO: the methods you listed should definitely be part of a DAO.

To answer your specific question, a DAO should not leak any database specific objects, it can leak some database concepts though as long as they are not specific to a database vendor.

So no, you should not return a MySQL result set. But you could create a generic result set that wraps a MySQL result set and that may work with higher level concepts (extracting whole objects instead of extracting columns).

Edit: My intent is not to lead you to actually build a result set wrapper, you could also simply return an array of objects like you initially suggested. This was just an example.

Comment: Cool thanks, I've done some of this type of work in the ASP world, but all my PHP scripts to date have been basic procedural scripts.  I'm trying to turn my php apps into oop php apps.

Comment: "in DAO, you should not return a MySQL result set. But you could create a generic result set. " is'nt this Repository job? to return generic object(s)

Answer (score -1):

For this you can make a class that contains 3 methods One that Create connection to database, second one is that close the connection and third one that executes the SQL Query

```
<?php
class Database{

    public function con_open(){
        $con = mysql_connect("domain","username","password");
            if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);
    }

    public function query($sql){
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$result){

            }else{      
                    return $result;
                }
    }

    public function fetch($result){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return $row;
    }

    public function con_close(){
         mysql_close($con);
    }
}


$db = new Database();

?>
```

Hope this will helpful to you

Comment: Not only should you not use the `mysql_*` extension but your example does not allow to change the connection details without explicitly changing the code.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a DAO (used for accessing one specific table in a database), not a Database class.